# How Do I Use PHP Includes to Display HTML pages?

Tags: php, html, css

I have my web page setup to use a new management system, but would also like to use some basic html pages for other content (such as images or whatever), and I seem to remember from years ago that there was a way to use PHP to load HTML pages that are not formatted into a content area, which I assume are DIVs.

I also seem to remember that I didn't have to create an if statement, but I'm not sure and quite honestly I'm awfully confused about how to do this. A friend used to do this coding for me way back when, so the way it was setup was that all I had to do was tell my navigation where to find the file and it would load it inside of my index.php file.

Hopefully my question is clear, but if not, my website is [right here](http://dbzfinalcut.com), and I just want my HTML files to load into the are with the content image, but only the grey portion (which I do have a DIV set up for). Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `include` or `require`... dude, use google

Comment: Obviously I know that it uses includes, I actually put that in my title. I'm having issues with the syntax, which I feel like could have been gathered by reading the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is by using require and include.
for more details, you can visit the following link:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

For example:

```
<?php include 'footer.html';?>
```

Comment: I have read through that article, so for what I want to do, will I have to build an if statement, since I want to point to multiple pages or do I have it backwards?

Comment: I meant to ask more; or should I convert my index to HTML and then create an index.php that handles my includes for the content div on my index.html?

Comment: If you want to use php in a page, then it must be a PHP page. And the portion where you want to display html page data, just include it in the page at the position where you want it. @ChrisBlackmon

Comment: Which is using this syntax from the W3 site right? <div class="menu">
<?php include 'menu.php';?>
</div> Sorry for the questions, I'm working ahead of my college courses so PHP is relatively foreign, even through reading up on it I haven't had much practice with. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Yes, this is a w3school link. You can get more info at the PHP manual itself. http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php @ChrisBlackmon